# Removing source from MapSnapshotter

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, snapshot

I am using MapSnapshotter to take screenshot of the map with polylines added. Due to the requirements, I do it in the foreground service. I need to take screenshot each second, however after first screenshot I receive error "Cannot add source twice". How can I delete the source after adding it with MapSnapshotter? Should I use other approach in this scenario?

```
            val lineLayer = LineLayer("route-line-layer", "route-line-layer-source")
                .withProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.lineColor(ColorUtils.colorToRgbaString(Color.BLUE)),
                    PropertyFactory.lineWidth(5f),
                    PropertyFactory.lineCap(Property.LINE_CAP_ROUND),
                    PropertyFactory.lineJoin(Property.LINE_JOIN_ROUND)
                )
            lineSource = GeoJsonSource("route-line-layer-source",linestring)

            navBuilderBC = com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style.Builder()
                .fromUri(NavigationStyles.NAVIGATION_DAY_STYLE)
                .withLayer(lineLayer)
                .withSource(lineSource!!)
                .withImage("USER_ICON", userIcon) 
                .withLayer(userPoint)
                .withSource(userSource)

            val options = MapSnapshotter.Options(screen_x, screen_y)
                .withStyleBuilder(navBuilderBC)

            mapSnapshotter = MapSnapshotter(context, options)
```